# Call function from both parent in multiple Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

EDIT: hard to explain myself in english so i'll try with a 'Sample' code.

```
class Character {
    public:
        Character(void); //constructor
        int     getAttack(void) const; // return this->_attack;
        int     getDef(void) const; // return this->_def;
        int     getSpeed(void) const; // return this->_speed;
        void    setAttack(int val); //this->_attack = val;
        void    setDef(int val); //this->_def = val;
        void    setSpeed(int val); //this->_speed = val;

    private:
        int     _attack;
        int     _def;
        int     _speed;
};


Character::Character(void) : _attack(1), _def(1), _speed(1) {

    return ;
}
```

Character stats are : 1 / 1 / 1

---

```
class Strong : public virtual Character {

    public:
        Strong(void); //constructor
};

Strong::Strong(void) : Character() {

    this->setAttack(100);
    this->setDef(100);
    this->setSpeed(1);
    return;
}
```

Strong stats are : 100 / 100 / 1

---

```
class Quick : public virtual Character {

    public:
        Quick(void); //constructor
};

Quick::Quick(void) : Character() {

    this->setAttack(1);
    this->SetDef(1);
    this->setSpeed(100);
    return;
}
```

Quick stats are : 1 / 1 / 100

---

```
class Super : public Strong, public Quick {

    public:
        Quick(void); //constructor
};

Super::Super(void) : Character(), Strong(), Quick() {

    this->setAttack(Strong::getAttack());
    this->setDef(Strong::getDef());
    this->setSpeed(Quick::getSpeed());
    return;
}
```

Super stats always are equal as Quick (or Strong if i swap order).

Any idea why ?

How can i initialize Super's Attack & Def from the values of his parent 'Strong' and initialize his speed value from the speed value of Quick please ?

Comment: Reread your own question to fix the typo that destroys the meaning of the question.  Maybe explain a bit better anyway.  Then it might be that a `using` declaration does what you want.

Comment: Your design does not make any sense. What business-domain entity does `Both` inherited from both `Man` and `Woman` represent? Are you confusing inheritance with child bearing?

Comment: Now that you edited the question to create the problem you say you are trying to fix, **WHY?**  You would get the behavior you want in `Super` if you didn't make that edit to `Strong` or `Quick`.  But any direct use of `Strong` or `Quick` is unchanged by that edit.  So what are you trying to fix with a change that creates a problem for no apparent benefit?  You can't get better advice on a solution without a clearer example of the requirements.

Comment: I want to know how explicitly initialized attributes from parent's values. Because i can not know if the 2nd parent override or not a specific value that had higher value from the 1st parent. @JSF

Comment: If you don't care much about efficiency (or trust the optimizer to fix it) you could construct local variables of type `Strong` and `Quick` with your `Super` constructor.  Then copy from those to the object being constructed.

Comment: Actually, construct local Strong/Quick in Super's Constructor could be a solution. There is no way to get value of Strong's attributes before Quick override them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: now that your edit changed the question, your requirements are back to being unclear.  But here is one (possibly overkill) approach to replacing your useless code, that I commented on in my original answer (which I left below).

```
Strong strong;  // Local variables to copy info from
Quick quick;
setAttack(strong.getAttack());
setDef(strong.getDef());
setSpeed(quick.getSpeed());
```

---

(Earlier answer, before the question was changed)

These operations all do nothing:

```
this->setAttack(Strong::getAttack());
this->setDef(Strong::getDef());
this->setSpeed(Quick::getSpeed());
```

The specifications `Strong::` vs. `Quick::` do nothing there because the three `get` functions all come from the same copy of `Character` regardless of which way they are inherited.  The three `set` calls just rewrite the value that was read.

But with or without those useless lines, the code should do what you wanted, not what you reported.  The `Character` constructor is called only once, before either `Strong` or `Quick`, so that is the only point where the values of `1` are stored.  Then each of `Strong` and `Quick` constructors (in the sequence you defined them) is called changing those `1`s to `100`s.

So if your tests showed otherwise, the problem is in code you didn't post.  Try posting the complete code of the test.

Below is a test of what you posted, with the useless code removed and the rest completed into a minimal test program:

You asked:

> How can i initialize Super's Attack & Def from the values of his
>   parent 'Strong' and initialize his speed value from the speed value of
>   Quick

As you can see by running this code, that is the way your code already works.  Notice (from the cout's I added) the sequence in which the constructors execute.  And notice (also from the output of those cout's that the three data members of `Character` exist in just one place within the object and are incrementally modified by the constructors in sequence.

```
#include <iostream>


class Character {
    public:
        Character(void); //constructor
        int     getAttack(void) const { return this->_attack; }
        int     getDef(void) const { return this->_def; }
        int     getSpeed(void) const { return this->_speed; }
        void    setAttack(int val) {this->_attack = val; }
        void    setDef(int val) {this->_def = val;}
        void    setSpeed(int val) {this->_speed = val; }

    private:
        int     _attack;
        int     _def;
        int     _speed;
};


Character::Character(void) : _attack(1), _def(1), _speed(1) {

    std::cout << "Character: "<< getAttack() << " " << getDef() << " "<< getSpeed() << std::endl;
}

class Strong : public virtual Character {

    public:
        Strong(void); //constructor
};

Strong::Strong(void) : Character() {

    this->setAttack(100);
    this->setDef(100);
    std::cout << "Strong: "<< getAttack() << " " << getDef() << " "<< getSpeed() << std::endl;
}

class Quick : public virtual Character {

    public:
        Quick(void); //constructor
};

Quick::Quick(void) : Character() {

    this->setSpeed(100);
    std::cout << "Quick: "<< getAttack() << " " << getDef() << " "<< getSpeed() << std::endl;
}

class Super : public Strong, public Quick {

    public:
        Super(void); //constructor
};

Super::Super(void) : Character(), Strong(), Quick() {

    std::cout << "Super: "<< getAttack() << " " << getDef() << " "<< getSpeed() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  Super test;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, if i understood you right its mean that is normal if all the 'getAttak() function' return the same value which is the value of the last 'parent' (Quick in my example).

if in my Super's constructor i do:

std::cout << Character::getAttack() std::endl;

std::cout << Strong::getAttack() std::endl;

std::cout << Quick::getAttack() std::endl;

The three will output '1' ? which is the value of Quick cause i instance it last ?

Comment: How can i initialize Super's Attack & Def from the values of his parent 'Strong' and initialize his speed value from the speed value of Quick please ? @JSF

Comment: That edit to my answer looked like an adjustment to the question, not the answer.  So I rejected it.  If you want to adjust the question, do so in an edit to the question.  But with that proposed adjustment, first think through what you are trying to accomplish with virtual inheritance (should that data be shared or not shared?).

Answer (score 3):

You should use the scope resolution operator `::`.

For instance if you want to call `Man` version of funcion use `both.Man::punch("bad guy")`, for the other one, analogicaly use `both.Woman::punch("bad guy")`

Comment: i  would like to define his own punch function like both::punch(target) { man::punch(target); return;}

But its does not seems to work..

Comment: @Mickael_42 You can do that and any problem with it should be discussed in another question, unless you can find the answer on your own. And remember about http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve